# BouncyCastle Symmetric Cipher algorithm with output same length as input

Tags: c#, security, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to create a BouncyCastle Cipher algorithm using their CSharp API that meets the following criteria:

- Output is same length as input
- Small variations in input (a few bytes) produce a large variation in the output
- Handles very small input (between 10 and 16 bytes)

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I have tried AES/CTR/NoPadding but while that meets the first and third criteria it doesn't meet the second - repeated encryption with small variations in input produced only minor changes in the output.

Comment: Uuhm, seems to me like you're trying to hash some data, for which the actual hash algorithms (SHA) are better. Why does the output have to be the same length as the input?

Comment: I'm not hashing. This algorithm needs to be reversible. Hashes are not. Besides, hash algorithm produce fixed length output.
Output needs to be same length as output due to limitations in the size of the destination of the encrypted data.

Comment: If you change your CTR nonce each time you encrypt, then the output will always look different. Is that sufficient?

Comment: As long as that still meets the other two criteria, yes. How would I go about doing that? If I had enough bandwidth, I'd generate a random IV and embed it in the output message, but I don't. I'm using a key generated using an ECDH agreement and the IV is derived from input as well.

Comment: CTR mode *REQUIRES* the nonce to non-repeating for a given key. CTR mode is XOR based, so multiple ciphertext messages produced with the same key&nonce means really trivial recovery of the plaintext using only the messages.

Comment: Is your plaintext always going to be less than 16 bytes?

Comment: @jbtule: Yes always. 13 bytes to be exact. The output needs to be a total of 18 bytes including 5 unencrypted bytes. Otherwise I'd use a pseudo-random nonce and include it in the output somehow.

Comment: CTR mode doesn't need a pseudo-random nonce, just needs to be a non-repeating (could be a counter), is your 5 bytes of unencrypted non-repeating?

Comment: 5 unencrypted bytes could be repeated but the remaining 8 bytes won't.
The structure is as follows:

Plain text = 8 non-repeating bytes + 5 possibly repeating bytes

Cipher text = 13 bytes

Message text = Cipher text + the 5 bytes from above (they are matched with that contained in the cipher text and also used to look up/derive the appropriate decryption key)